# Center image horizontally with dynamic width with overflow hidden parent

Tags: css

I have a parent div that has a variable height. Inside is an image that must be 100% of the height of it's parent.

I can achieve this pretty easily in css like this:

```
.parent {
    width: 640px;
    min-height: 560px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parent img {
    min-height: 560px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Only problem is that the img will always be left aligned. How do I center it in it's parent?

If I use a background image, the image won't be resized to fit the total height of the parent. I don't want to use the css3 background-size property due to it's lack of support in ie7 & 8.

There are a few questions on stackoverflow related to this, but none of them (that I can find) address the issue in relation to a variable width & height image.

Comment: .parent {text-align:center} Would center all items within this div

Comment: margin:auto will not work as the width is not specified. Does not work on percentages.

Comment: what are the actual dimensions of the image?

Comment: text-align:center; doesn't work, because the image is overflowing outside of the bounds of the parent.

Comment: The actual dimensions of the image could change - it doesn't matter if the image is stretched large than it actually is.

Comment: Just use background-width: cover;

Comment: Cam - think you mean background-size: cover;. I specified that I wanted to avoid this. Thanks though.

Comment: Thats what I meant, bangin my head on a keyboard over a ecom issue on another website.

Comment: I don't think you'll find an acceptable solution to this problem, not if you need to support IE7.  It is nearly as crippled as IE6 when it comes to CSS support.  This is about as close as I could get http://tinker.io/7f576

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but since this question hasn't had an answer yet, I will put my solution here to help anyone struggling with this.

You will need 2 parent divs to achieve this, and basically the inner div will have larger width than any possible images inside it. We center it horizontally inside the outer div, and this way we can use text-align: center to align the image.

```css
.mask {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.imgctn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.imgctn img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  <div class="imgctn">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **text-align: center;** will do the trick:

```
.parent {
   text-align: center;
   width: 640px;
   min-height: 560px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.parent img {
   min-height: 560px;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately. The img width is greater than the parent width, so part of it is hidden due to the overflow:hidden. This stops text-align:center; from working.